# Rolling a 15 sided dice

Tags: statistics

A game of chance involves rolling a 15-sided die once. If a number from 1 to 3 comes up, you win 2 dollars. If the number 4 or 5 comes up, you win 10 dollars. If any other number comes up, you lose. If it costs 4 dollars to play, what is your expected net winnings?

I am not looking for the answer, but someone to help me figure out work the formula with me, so I can actually learn this. I am online all night!

Comment: -2.258 is the answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Imagine instead "rolling" 15 times, and you get each value once.  How much money would you win doing this?  How much would you spend?  Divide your net winnings for this scenario by 15 to discover your expectation.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: The expected net winning (in dollars) is
$$ \sum_z (z-4) \Pr[\text{you win $z$ dollars}] = \sum_z z \Pr[\text{you win $z$ dollars}] - 4. $$
Here the summation goes over all possible values you could win, in your case $0,2,10$ ($z=0$ corresponds to the case in which you lose).

Comment: Wonderful, thanks for that help buddy!

Comment: No, you'll have to solve it yourself. It's plugging numbers in a formula.